# Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException: JWT payload does not contain the required claims in file

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8

quisiera saber como puedo generar un token usando un arreglo customizado como referencia (el email pero sin la contrase#a) con jwt en laravel, estoy usando mi propia autenticacion, y estoy intentando hacer la parte de registrarse y verificacion de correo pero no he podido ni siquiera generar el token de la url para el correo... bien, necesito que el token al decodificarlo me traiga solamente el correo (si es posible ayudenme con eso XD) para decodificarlo a la hora de loguear al usuario.

He intentado cambiar en el archivo `config/jwt.php` los parametros del required claims pero no me ha funcionado asi:

```php
<?php

return [
    'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),
    'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),
    'refresh_ttl' => env('JWT_REFRESH_TTL', 20160),
    'algo' => env('JWT_ALGO', 'HS256'),
    'required_claims' => ['email'],
    'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),
    'blacklist_grace_period' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD', 0),
    'providers' => [
        'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,
        'auth' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Auth\Illuminate::class,
        'storage' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\Storage\Illuminate::class,
    ],
];
```

Este es mi `RegisterController.php` el cual se le hace la consulta en /api/auth/register/sendMail

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send the confirmation email to user, path: /api/auth/register/sendMail
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return Illuminate\Http\Resposne $response
     */
    public function sendMail(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'            => 'required|email',
            'name'             => 'required|string',
            'password'         => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $customClaims = ['email' => $request->get('email'), 'password' => $request->get('password')];
        $payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);
        $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
        return response()->json(compact('token'), 200);
    }
}
```

Hay que destacar que ese archivo me lo copie de una documentacion y no venia... tambien intente generar el secret de jwt (a ver si funciona por una magica razon) asi:

```sh
php artisan jwt:secret
```

lo genero en mi .env:

```
JWT_SECRET=CXDrR8teRJsQBEkyXXuOvrkDZUhvjmQmseNWz304zQ5IiStmI5WB9w8SigojHf4A
```

pero al ejecutar:

```sh
curl -sX POST -F 'email=q7slojwgkbi@wwjmp.com' -F 'name=pepito' -F 'password=password' http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register/sendMail | head -n 10
```

obtengo el siguiente error:`Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException: JWT payload does not contain the required claims in file /home/thecoderpro/Projects/php/mundo_parcela/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Validators/PayloadValidator.php on line 67`

Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Según tengo entendido JWT codifica lo que tenga como payload, así que solo pon como payload el email. En cuanto al error has probado con poner en el return ```json_encode($token)```

Comment: Acabo de intentar poner como payload: `$customClaims = ['email' => $request->get('email'),]; $payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);` solo el email y generado el token: `$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload)` y puesto el json_encode: `return response()->json(json_encode($token), 200)` pero sigue saliendo el error

Comment: Y tambien `return json_encode($token);` y tambien da el error